# How to apply just one beta-reduction to `λy.(λx.λy.yx)yz`?

Tags: parsing, rename, beta, lambda-calculus, reduction

How do I apply just one beta-reduction to `λy.(λx.λy.yx)yz`?

The correct answer is `λy.(λw.wy)z`.

Renaming is allowed only if necessary, and from the answer it is obvious renaming was used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first add some parentheses do make the structure more apparent, because maybe that's the reason you got confused:

```
λy.(λx.λy.yx)yz = λy.(((λx.λy.(yx))y)z)
```

On the outermost level, there is nothing to be done. But we can do a beta-reduction inside the `λy`, but first we need to an alpha renaming to avoid capturing the `y`:

```
    (λx.λy.(yx))y
--> (λx.λw.(wx))y   (alpha renaming y to w)
--> λw.wy           (beta)
```

Now putting this into the whole context:

```
    λy.(λx.λy.yx)yz
--> λy.(λx.λw.(wx))yz   (alpha renaming y to w)
--> λy.(λw.wy)z         (beta)
```

Comment: Thank you! Therefore, the key is to assign parenthesis following **Left-Left** & **λx.(as far as possible)** rules, before starting beta reduction.